# How to get values from a table in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In InsertData class, I want to get values from Combobox `cbxCategory`  but I can't get because `dshang.tblCategory` is a table.

The error like:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'EntityObject.tblCategory'(this is a table)

```
Category dshang = new Category();
string category = cbxCategory.SelectedValue.ToString();
dshang.tblCategory = category;
```

In the Entity data model, I define it's a table. So, I can't get this values from this.

```
public partial class ListProduct
{
    public virtual tblCategory  tblCategory { get; set; }
}
```

And here contain class define table `tblPhanLoai`:

```
public partial class tblCategory 
{
    public tblCategory()
    {
        this.ListProducts = new HashSet<ListProduct>();
    }

    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string DonViTinh { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ListProduct> ListProducts { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning a simple string to an object...

Comment: Yep, this is an object in entity framework. I don't know how to get values from an object

Comment: make the tblCategory property of Category class of type string

Comment: if the **combobox** selected value is the Description from tblCategory then you can assign  `string category = cbxCategory.SelectedValue.ToString();  
dshang.tblCategory.Description = category;`